# How to find the row number of all occurances of a text value in excel column

Tags: excel

I'm really not familiar at all with excel, so your help is greatly appreciated.

Here, I want to find the row numbers of the first occurrence of the text value "dll_ctrl0", the second row index, etc...

For example, in the picture below, I'd like an expression that would return the first occurrence (35), another expression that would return the second (36), and so on...

So far, I've been able to find the row index of the FIRST occurrence using the expression: 
`=MATCH("dll_ctrl0",'random_sheet_name'!C:C,0)`. 
This returns 35. I also want an expression that will return 36, one that returns 37 (etc...), all corresponding to the picture below.

[image: I'd like to find the row numbers of all occurrences of "dll_ctrl0", for example.]

Answer (score 2):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want all the rows for Springfield.  We will use `MATCH()` to find the first row.   We will use a second `MATCH()` to find the next row.  The second match will begin just below the first one.  We will continue until there are no more matches.  In **D1** we enter:

```
 Springfield
```

In **D2** enter:

```
=MATCH($D$1,A:A,0)
```

In **D3** enter:

```
=MATCH($D$1,INDEX(A:A,D2+1):INDEX(A:A,9999),0)+D2
```

and copy **D3** downwards:

[image]

Once we hit the error we can stop.  Each formula relies on the formula above it.  Because the formulas use only the `MATCH()` and `INDEX()` functions, this approach can be use with older as well as newer versions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=aggregate(15, 6, row($1:$999)/('random_sheet_name'!C$1:C$999="dll_ctrl0"), row(1:1))
```

Fill down for subsequent row numbers. Wrap in IFERROR if you don't want error codes when you run out of matches.